# How to use aggregate function in comparison

Tags: sql, db2

Im trying to run this query in DB2:

```
SELECT  A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID, A.SENT_TS, B.SENT_TS FROM ecom.EMAIL_HIST A 
INNER JOIN ecom.EMAIL_RTM_HIST B
ON A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID = B.EMAIL_ADDR_ID
WHERE max(b.SENT_TS) > max(a.SENT_TS)
GROUP BY A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID;
```

On trying to run the above query, I get this below error message.

```
SQL Error [42903]: Invalid use of an aggregate function or OLAP function..SQLCODE=-120, SQLSTATE=42903, DRIVER=3.64.114
```

Any pointers on what mistake I have done here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution 1

```
SELECT  A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID, max(A.SENT_TS) maxsendTS_A, max(B.SENT_TS) maxsendTS_B
FROM ecom.EMAIL_HIST A INNER JOIN ecom.EMAIL_RTM_HIST B
ON A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID = B.EMAIL_ADDR_ID
GROUP BY A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID
having max(b.SENT_TS) > max(a.SENT_TS)
```

Comment: Thank you Esperento57. I added 'as' to make the maxsendTS_A and B and the query worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `having` clause:

```
SELECT A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID, MAX(A.SENT_TS), MAX(B.SENT_TS)
FROM ecom.EMAIL_HIST A INNER JOIN 
     ecom.EMAIL_RTM_HIST B
     ON A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID = B.EMAIL_ADDR_ID
GROUP BY A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID
HAVING max(b.SENT_TS) > max(a.SENT_TS);
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff. I had to make the A.SENT_TS, B.SENT_TS as max(A.SENT_TS) and max(B.SENT_TS) and the query worked.

Comment: @Ganesh . . . Yes . . . I wasn't even looking at the `select` when I answered.

Answer (score 0):

solution 2

modify your query like this

```
select * from (
SELECT  A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID, max(A.SENT_TS) maxsendTS_A, max(B.SENT_TS) maxsendTS_B
FROM ecom.EMAIL_HIST A INNER JOIN ecom.EMAIL_RTM_HIST B
ON A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID = B.EMAIL_ADDR_ID
GROUP BY A.EMAIL_ADDR_ID
) tmp where maxsendTS_B>maxsendTS_A
```